# Connecting to MSSQL-Server 2008 under Zend server

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, zend-server

Hi I'm currently trying to connect to MSSQL-Server-2008 using php on a Zend (web) server.
I've tried out a few things now but always end up getting:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:\Zend\ZendServer\lib\phpext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll' - The required module was not found
*(sry if the error message sounds a bit strange I translated it manually into english)*

First step I did was to download:
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client

2nd step was that I downloaded:
SQLSRV20.EXE and extracted the files into the phpext directory.

3rd step was that I tried to turn on:
pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9
and / or 
pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9
And restarted php.

Regardless of what I did I received the above error message.
Thus every time I try to connect to the mssql server I get an error message:
*PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()*

Are there any additional steps needed?
(PHP Version I use is: 5.3.9 with a very new version of the zend server).

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the Zend server itself there are SQL drivers install them along it  with general installation.Once the installation is done turn on these extensions sqlsrv,pdo_sqlsrv in the php console.I don't know the exact reason but those extensions which come with SQLSRV20.EXE are not compatible and those cannot be loaded.

Regards,
Sri